# Alternativas con @import

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, importación

estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto web y quisiera saber si hay otra forma de importar paquetes en un archivo css, actualmente estoy utilizando la clausula @import, pero desearía saber si hay otra forma de hacer lo mismo sin utilizar @import.

```
@import url(styleParticles.min.css);
@import url(parallax.min.css);
@import url(plugins/owl.carousel.min.css);
@import url(plugins/owl.theme.min.css);
@import url(plugins/owl.transitions.min.css);
@import url(plugins/animate.min.css);
@import url(plugins/magnific-popup.min.css);
@import url(plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.css);
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres conseguir que no puedes mediante @import?

Comment: De acuerdo a un superior, esto es considerado como mala practica y afecta al rendimiento de la página

Comment: @user224275 Bajo mi punto de vista, no considero que sea una mala práctica, lo único que hace es traer otro archivo CSS al actual, no dejando motivo para ser una mala práctica, una alternativa sería importar los otros estilos en el HTML con la etiqueta `<link>`, para más contexto acerca de por qué `@import` no es una mala práctica, revisa [esta respuesta en StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709625/is-using-import-declarations-a-bad-practice#:~:text=Using%20the%20import%20rule%20is,to%20see%20the%20css%20applied.)

Comment: @anythingg por lo que lei [aca](https://www.googleessimple.com/wiki/pagespeed/evita-usar-import/) carga los documentos secuencialmente. Entonces recien se consideraria mala practica tener "muchos" imports y no solo "pocos" verdad? (Esto si, depende de la cantidad de informacion en el css)

Comment: No entiendo; ¿por que mejor no usar @use con sass?

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

```
let lnk = document.createElement('link');
        lnk.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
        lnk.setAttribute('type','text/css');
        lnk.setAttribute('href','css/documento.css');
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(lnk);
```

Hacemos un link, le metemos la url y ya tendrías otra, es dinámico, yo lo he probado en varias ocasiones ya, así que por esa parte no hay problema. Lo malo es que se tiene que controlar 100% en js cuando quieres agregarlo o quitarlo.

Pero vamos, desde mi punto de vista me parece mas útil el import.